# How do I write Firebase Rules that compare Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser UID to the UID in Firebase Authentication

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

If I set Firebase Rules for `".read": true` my app works correctly. If I simply require an auth'd user (see below), Firebase throws an exception "Permission Denied" What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Here are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

**LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
using PelletPirate.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using PelletPirate.Services;

namespace PelletPirate.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
        IAuth auth;

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuth>();
        }

        private async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Email.Text = "connor@connor.com";
            Password.Text = "connor";

            var token = await auth.LoginWithEmailPassword(Email.Text, Password.Text);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Logged inToken is: " + token + "******** UID is: " + App.G_currentuser);

            if (token != string.Empty)
            {
                Email.Text = null;
                Password.Text = null;
                var OwnerObject = await firebaseHelper.SetGlobalOwnersController(App.G_currentuser);
                App.G_controller = OwnerObject.controller;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Returned back to LoginPage Global Controller set to: [" + App.G_controller + "] <<--- controller should be in the brackets!");
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//loggedin");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Authentication Failed", "E-mail or password are incorrect. Try again!", "OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthIOS.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Foundation;
using Firebase.Auth;
using PelletPirate.Interfaces;
using PelletPirate.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AuthIOS))]

namespace PelletPirate.iOS
{
    class AuthIOS : IAuth
    {
        public async Task<string> LoginWithEmailPassword(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                SignOut();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In AuthIOS and BEFORE SignIn to Firebase (should be NULL) and Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser is: [" + Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser + "] << inside these brackets!");
                var user = await Auth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithPasswordAsync(email, password);
                App.G_currentuser = user.User.Uid;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In AuthIOS AFTER SignIn and Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser is: [" + Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser + "] << inside these brackets!");
                return await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR in login caught -->> " + e + " <<-- error diplay here");
                return "";
            }
        }

        public bool SignOut()
        {
            try
            {
                _ = Auth.DefaultInstance.SignOut(out NSError error);
                return error == null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AuthIOS SignOut Failed " + e); }
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool IsSignedIn()
        {
            var user = Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;
            return user != null;
        }
    }

}
```

**FirebaseHelper.cs (Services)**

```
using Firebase.Database;
using PelletPirate.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PelletPirate.Services
{
    public class FirebaseHelper
    {
        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://pelletpirate-auth-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");

        public async Task<Owner> SetGlobalOwnersController(string userid) // used to get the Controller name and return it to be assigned to a global variable
        {
            return (await firebase.Child("owners").OnceAsync<Owner>()).Select(item => new Owner
            {
                userId = userid,
                controller = item.Object.controller,
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
 
    }
}
```

Any help or ideas to check would be much appreciated. I've been struggling with this all week and can't seem to get a breakthrough.  thanks, Brian

Comment: Security rules on their own are meaningless without seeing the code that exercises them. Please show the *code* that is causing problems.

Comment: 1) When you step through this code in a debugger, which specific line isn't doing what you expect it to do? 2) I highly recommend trying to reproduce the problem in a single fragment of code, without any dependencies on UI elements. Check out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints on how to maximize the chance that someone can help.

Comment: You might want to log `Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;` right before that line, to see if it shows a value. If it *does*, then that user's ID token will be passed with the call to the database. If it doesn't, the user isn't signed in to Firebase when you call the database, no matter what your other code may say.

Comment: There are a lot of code snippets now, which makes it really hard to follow what's going on. That's why I asked for you to add a single log statement of the value directly from Firebase Auth to where the problem occurs. I highly recommend reading the firsts link I provided, as it's the best way I know of to increase the chance we can help.

Comment: Hi Frank, I've added the minimal example code above and the log output showing the `Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser` output. Any help you can provide on what to check next would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that. You're logging `App.G_currentuser`, but are then reading `firebase.Child(ChildOwner)`. Your rules only grant the user access to `firebase.Child(App.G_currentuser)`.

Comment: Ok I know I am missing something here, and I am excited for the "Eureka!" moment to form in my mind, I hope. I've changed my Rules to just make sure the user is authenticated `".read": "auth != null"` I would expect this to work but it does not. I am authenticated. How would I write the rule to let ANY Firebase authenticated user to access?

Comment: Hmm... I'm indeed not sure why those rules would reject. And you're saying that allowing `".read": true` makes the error go away? (just double checking it it's really an auth problem, as I don't see why it would be)

Comment: yes, correct, if I make `".read": true` it works fine.

Comment: Hmmm.... I just don't see what you could be doing wrong. Sorry about that. I hope somebody else spots it.

Comment: the exception thrown is requesting `https://pelletpirate.firebaseio.com/owners/.json` I am wondering why the .json is appended which makes the URL invalid... if I remove the `.json`, it resolves to my DB... but again if I just open up the rules it works fine as is,.. very frustrating. not sure what to even try.

Comment: You can use `https://pelletpirate.firebaseio.com/owners/.json` without the final slash, but Firebase should accept both URLs as equivalent.

Comment: Hi StackOverflow community: Any help would be appreciated on this gremlin!  I can't figure it out.  I can provide a minimal complete project example in a ZIP file if the code above is not enough to figure it out or if anyone can take a look. Thank you. Brian